# How do I validate dynamically created forms in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm currently dynamically creating a custom form widget (Row) and am wondering what the best way to validate each form was. By attempting to use a global FormState key, nothing works as the key is shared by each form instance (I assume).

This creates issues such as the keyboard immediately dropping out upon focusing on a textfield.

Was wondering if anyone has a solution to this or could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Root Widget:

```
class ExerciseTable extends ConsumerWidget {
  final Exercise exercise;
  ExerciseTable({@required this.exercise});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final _exerciseTableController = watch(exerciseTableControllerProvider);

    /*
    * Logic of where I build the form rows dynamically
    */
    List<Widget> _buildFormRows() {
      List<Widget> rows = [];
      int sets = int.parse(exercise.sets);
      for (int i = 1; i < sets; i++) {
        rows.add(
          _BuildExerciseRow(
            set: i.toString(),
          ),
        );
      }
      return rows;
    }

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text(
          exercise.exerciseName,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 8),
        YoutubePlayerTile(
          url: exercise.exerciseURL,
        ),
        const SizedBox(height: 8),
        _BuildRowHeader(),
        Column(children: _buildFormRows())
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Individual Form Row Widget:

```
/**
 * * Form Rows
 */
class _BuildExerciseRow extends StatelessWidget {
  final String set;
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _kgTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  final _repsTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  _BuildExerciseRow({this.set});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
      child: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Text(set),
            const SizedBox(width: 15),
            Text("-"),
            const SizedBox(width: 15),
            _BuildInputTextField(
                controller: _kgTextEditingController,
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return "Please enter some text";
                  } else
                    return "";
                }),
            // const SizedBox(width: 15),
            _BuildInputTextField(
              controller: _repsTextEditingController,
            ),
            TickBox(onTap: () => _formKey.currentState.validate())
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _BuildInputTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  // final int keyValue;
  final String Function(String) validator;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  _BuildInputTextField({this.validator, @required this.controller});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2),
      height: 39,
      width: 80,
      child: TextFormField(
          validator: validator,
          inputFormatters: [
            LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(6),
          ],
          controller: controller,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5, left: 10),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1),
            ),
          ),
          onChanged: (value) => {}),
    );
  }
}
```

Custom TextFormField Widget:

```
class _BuildInputTextField extends StatelessWidget {
  // final int keyValue;
  final String Function(String) validator;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  _BuildInputTextField({this.validator, @required this.controller});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 2),
      height: 39,
      width: 80,
      child: TextFormField(
          validator: validator,
          inputFormatters: [
            LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(6),
          ],
          controller: controller,
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5, left: 10),
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1),
            ),
          ),
          onChanged: (value) => {}),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing your `validator` callback as

```
validator: (value) {
                  if (value.isEmpty) {
                    return "Please enter some text";
                  } else
                    return null;
                }),
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!

It was super simple, I forgot to convert `_BuildExerciseRow` to a Stateful Widget. (In my case, a Consumer Widget from Riverpod which extends StatefulWidget).